# How can I create static HTML table-files from a CSV file for each row with PHP?

Tags: php, html, html-table, import-from-csv

I want to automatically create static HTML sites with a single table in each of it. The whole purpose of this is to build a small library collection with basic metadata (about 4000 datasets). 
I got the data in a text file (CSV), semicolon separated. 
Now for every line in the CSV file, I want to create a single table, formatted like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td >Title:</td><td>A Game of Thrones</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td >Author:</td><td>Martin, George R.R.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >Published:</td><td>New York : Bantam Books</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td >Year:</td><td>1996</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So it's important to assign each field in the line to its "fieldname" in the first td's.
Additionally, I would like to locally save the tables in HTML files.
I tried to print the echo somehow but it doesn't seem to be possible (I guess because echo doesn't work like a variable). 
Also, I know that a dynamic script pulling the data from MYSQL would probably be easier, but for certain reasons, static HTML sites better fit my needs. 
I found this example:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("10Titel_Semi.txt", "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    echo "<p> $num Felder in Zeile $row: <br /></p>\n";
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
    }
}
fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

but it just writes all the information straight forward.
So it has to be some kind of loop working for each line and then give out a HTML file (the file name would be the ID from each line). I tried a lot with arrays and foreach loops but it don't get all of the mechanisms yet. 
Is this possible, or does someone has a better idea? 
Since I'm completely new to PHP and almost new to programming in general, I would be grateful for some help. The code does not need to be elegant or something, I just need it to work.

Edit: I thought about something like this:

```
<tr>
<td>Author:</td><td>$data[1]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Published</td><td>$data[2]</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Year:</td><td>$data[3]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

where I put out an array of each line/row as a variable in the HTML table...
hope this helps understanding my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looping over lines and columns in that code, you should do something like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td >Title:</td><td>A Game of Thrones</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td >Author:</td><td>Martin, George R.R.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >Published:</td><td>New York : Bantam Books</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td >Year:</td><td>1996</td>
</tr>

<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("10Titel_Semi.txt", "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    echo "<tr>";
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        echo "<td>" . $data[$c] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
fclose($handle);
}
?>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works to iterate over the rows, but I need to assign each field to its fieldname (title, author, etc...). 
It's not supposed to be a usual table with a header row, but a column with the fieldname and a column with the field itself.
Something like this:  
Title:            A Game of Thrones   
Author:        Martin, George R.R.  
Published:   New York : Bantam Books    
Year:           1996